# Getting an empty file when served by django

Tags: python, django, download

I have the following code for managing file download through django.

```
def serve_file(request, id):

    file = models.X.objects.get(id=id).file #FileField
    file.open('rb')
    wrapper = FileWrapper(file)
    mt = mimetypes.guess_type(file.name)[0]
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=mt)

    import unicodedata, os.path
    filename = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', os.path.basename(file.name)).encode("utf8",'ignore')
    filename = filename.replace(' ', '-') #Avoid browser to ignore any char after the space

    response['Content-Length'] = file.size
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)

    #print response
    return response
```

Unfortunately, my browser get an empty file when downloading.

The printed response seems correct:

```
Content-Length: 3906
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=toto.txt

blah blah ....
```

I have similar code running ok. I don't see what can be the problem. Any idea?

PS: I have tested the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3213548/117092) and get the same behavior

Update:
Replacing `wrapper = FileWrapper(file)` by `wrapper = file.read()` seems to fix the problem

Update: If I comment the `print response`, I get similar issue:. the file is empty. Only difference: FF detects a 20bytes size. (the file is bigger than this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File object is an interable, and a generator. It can be read only once before being exausted. Then you have to make a new one, of use a method to start at the begining of the object again (e.g: `seek()`).

`read()` returns a string, which can be read multiple times without any problem, this is why it solves your issue.

So just make sure that if you use a file like object, you don't read it twice in a row. E.G: don't print it, then returns it.

Comment: Good point! However i've commented the print and still have similar behavior (in fact, i've added the print to try to understand the pb). See my update

Comment: Yeah, but what prooves you that the response is itered over only once ? The response use your file wrapper afterall to et its content after all.

Answer (score 0):

From [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FieldFile.open):

> FieldFile.open(mode='rb') Behaves like the standard Python open()
>   method and opens the file associated with this instance in the mode
>   specified by mode.

If it works like pythons `open` then it should return a file-object, and should be used like this:

```
f = file.open('rb')
wrapper = FileWrapper(f)
```

Comment: it seems that file.open doesn't return anything but modify the file instance