# Django/Mezzanine/Cartridge: Providing Non-HTML Download

Tags: django, download, mime-types, mime

An authenticated user has some digital content under account page and should be able to download it. I do not want to provide a direct HTML link but just deliver the file on clicking download. I have looked at:

[Django Book: Chapter 13](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter13.html)

[Django download file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213060/django-download-file-not-working)

[Django download file empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141682/django-download-file-empty)

which seem to be relevant solutions and have worked for others. What I see however is that, it seems to be doing the right thing in the sense that:
  - Firstly, there are no errors printed or crashes
  - Dumping out the HttpResponse that is generated to stdout, shows presence of binary data.

But it doesn't download anything, nor does the browser ask if the user thinks this is safe content to download as would if you were downloading some PDF from a website.

I am inclined to think, it could be a settings.py issue that is set as a security measure that might not allow the download. But it could be anything else.

Here is an example of what I have:

```py
filePath = os.path.abspath('static/media/files/' + fileName)
wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filePath), 'r')
contentType = mimetypes.guess_type(filePath)[0]
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type = contentType)
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filePath)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s/' % smart_str(os.path.basename(filePath))

return response
```

Other things I have tried:

```py
with open(filePath, 'rb') as f:
    return HttpResponse(f.read(), mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

Python: 2.7.4

Pip freeze:

```
Cartridge==0.8.2
Django==1.5.4
Fabric==1.8.0
Mezzanine==1.4.16
PIL==1.1.7
Pillow==2.2.1
Pillow-PIL==0.1dev
South==0.8.2
argparse==1.2.1
bleach==1.2.2
cartridge-stripe==0.1.3
distribute==0.6.34
django-zebra==0.4.3
ecdsa==0.9
filebrowser-safe==0.2.30
grappelli-safe==0.2.22
gunicorn==18.0
html5lib==0.95
oauthlib==0.6.0
paramiko==1.12.0
pisa==3.0.33
psycopg2==2.5.1
pycrypto==2.6
pytz==2013.7
requests==1.2.3
requests-oauthlib==0.3.3
stripe==1.9.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: I was using that in a Class Based View. I changed it to a view function and the simple code from [DjangoBook: Chapter 13](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter13.html) seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have a problem with your path.

does this shows the correct path? >>

> filePath = os.path.abspath('static/media/files/' + fileName)

I am asking this because you are pointing a media directory which is under static folder with the same level of your views.py file.

if it is correct path, that means u have another misunderstanding problem too. Django doesn't serve neither media nor static files from a static/media path under a django module at production. Your media files must be in the place where your settings.MEDIA_ROOT shows **even in DEVELOPMENT**.

U may check your path correctness by debugging these lines and i think problem is about it because every other things seems fine.

Note: there should also a browser problem too.Check this also.